# Write a large text file with NIO

Tags: java, io, nio, filechannel

I write a large, approximately 1200 (+/- 200) mb , csv file for an offline report in my application. (A thread performs this job.) The data count may run around 50 million, so the query is run for every 50k rows. The query loop runs till empty fetch (for the given criteria). To write the data to the file, instead of using the Java streams, I tried the nio. It took me ~12 seconds to write a huge string with 50000 lines. The same code tried with BufferedWriter took around ~18-22 seconds. The nio approach code is given below. I want to know if this is the straight forward way to use the nio in writing a huge file? Anything I have overlooked, missed? Any other way, optimization and code improvement is welcome.

```
private static void writeData(FileChannel channel, String data) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = null;
    try {
        buffer = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(
                CharBuffer.wrap(data.toCharArray()));
        channel.write(buffer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private String writeReport() {
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pathToFile, true);
        FileChannel channel = out.getChannel();
        // db query
        while(iterate resultset) {
             // get row result
            writeData(channel, data);
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
      //log
    } finally {
      channel.close();
      out .close();
    }
}

//pseudo code with bufferedwriter
private String writeReport(Resultset rs, String file) {
    try {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file), 1024 * 10);
        int headerCount = 0;
        while(rs.next()) {
            String col1 = rs.getString(1);
            String col2 = rs.getString(2);
            String col3 = rs.getString(3);
            String col4 = rs.getString(4);
            String col5 = rs.getString(5);
            String colN= rs.getString(n); //nth column
            if(headerCount==0) {
                writeHeader(writer);
                headerCount++;
            }
            if(col1.equals(condition1)) {
                 writer.append(col1).append(",");
            }
            ......
            if(colN.equals(conditionN)) {
                 writer.append(colN).append(",").append(newLine());
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
      //log
    } finally {
      writer.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to write your file would probably be with a `BufferedWriter.` If that was slow I would want to see your code. NIO shouldn't be expected to deliver anything startling here, and the code you posted certainly won't be faster than a `BufferedWriter,` as it will do many more physical writes.

Comment: I ran a test now with the BufferedWriter, on avg it took 18-22 seconds to write the same. I rerun the test as I lost the earlier test results. Approach 1, I stores the results in a StringBuilder and write to the BufferedWriter in the end of iteration. (I got memory exception, so rewrote the approach 2). Approach 2, I form a string from the row results and write to the BufferedWriter, making more disk writes, resulting in 18 seconds. Approach 3, I have an optimal count which I check while iterating, write to the BufferedWriter when reached (then reset), resulting ~20 seconds.

Comment: @VijayVeeraraghavan The whole point of a buffered writer is to buffer multiple writes into one write, this means making writes directly to a BufferedWriter should be faster than the same number of writes to a StringBuilder which you later copy to the BufferedWriter.

Comment: Please tell us also how long it takes if you comment the call to writeData(). So we know how much time it needs to get all that data and go through it.

Comment: @VijayVeeraraghavan I didn't say anything about `StringBuffers.` Just write the data directly to the `BufferedWriter` as you generate it, and don't flush it either until you close it. You can write a million lines in a couple of seconds. Your time isn't going on I/O, it's going on futzing around with the `StringBuffer` and whatever else is inside your loop. Which you haven't showed us.

Comment: @EJP I will try to write directly to the BufferedWriter and check it.

Comment: @Ingo There are few if statements to check the status and other in some values of the columns. It should not take much time. Any way I will try to rephrase the question with some more information.

Comment: I wrote the values fetched from the database straight to the BufferedWriter which took the same 13 seconds of 50K lines.

Comment: @VijayVeeraraghavan I/O is not the problem here. I can write all 50 million lines in 6 seconds with a `BufferedWriter.` Please post the new code. Edit it into your question. You should also try your code without the writes. Clearly the input or your loop code is where the time is going.

Comment: Operating systems typically buffer writes for you, which is why you usually don't need a `BufferedWriter when writing in Java.

Comment: @Bill Nonsense. Using a `BufferedWriter` will save you up to 8191 out of 8192 system calls. The operating system cannot possibly do that for you.